# Proving $ \idotsint_{A}e^{t\left ( x_1+\ldots +x_n\right )}\,dx_1 \ldots dx_n=\left ( \frac{e^t-1}{t} \right )^n$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Let
$$A=\left \{ \left ( x_1,\ldots ,x_n \right )\in \mathbb{R}^n \,\Bigg|\sum\limits_{1\leq k\leq n}\frac{x_k}{k}\leq 1,x_1,\ldots,x_n\geq 0 \right \}$$
Prove that for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$  the equality holds
$$ \idotsint\limits_{A}e^{t\left ( x_1+\ldots +x_n\right )}\,dx_1 \ldots dx_n=\left ( \frac{e^t-1}{t} \right )^n$$
I tried to solve this problem using the method of mathematical induction, but nothing happened ... Are there any other ways ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $n=1$, the integral is
$$
  \int_0^1 e^{t x_1} dx_1 = \frac{1}{t} \left. e^{t x_1} \right|_{x=0}^1 = \frac{e^t-1}{t}.
$$
Suppose we have
$$
  \iint_A e^{t(x_1+\dotsb+x_n)} dV = \left( \frac{e^t-1}{t} \right)^n
$$
as claimed, for some particular $n$. Consider the integral in dimension $n+1$. Let's use $A$ to denote the region in $n$ dimensions, and $B$ for the region in dimension $n+1$:
$$
  A = \left\{ (x_1,\dotsc,x_n) \colon \sum \frac{x_k}{k} \leq 1, x_1,\dotsc,x_n \geq 0 \right\}, \\
  B = \left\{ (x_1,\dotsc,x_n,x_{n+1}) \colon \sum \frac{x_k}{k} \leq 1, x_1,\dotsc,x_{n+1} \geq 0 \right\}.
$$
For each $0 \leq u \leq n+1$, let $B_u = B \cap \{x_{n+1}=u\}$. Then
$$
  B_u = \left\{ (x_1,\dotsc,x_n,u) \colon \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} \frac{x_k}{k} \leq 1-\frac{u}{n+1}, x_1,\dotsc,x_n \geq 0 \right\},
$$
which can be obtained from $A$ by dilating by a factor of $1 - \frac{u}{n+1}$ (and translating by $u$ in the $x_{n+1}$ direction). Let $u' = 1 - \frac{u}{n+1}$, so
$$
  \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} \frac{x_k}{k} \leq u'
  \iff
  \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n} \frac{(x_k/u')}{k} \leq 1,
$$
which means $(x_1,\dotsc,x_n,u) \in B_u$ if and only if $(x_1/u',\dotsc,x_n/u') \in A$.
Substitute $(x'_1,\dotsc,x'_n) = (x_1/u',\dotsc,x_n/u')$ to get
$$
\begin{split}
  \iint_B e^{t(x_1+\dotsb+x_{n+1})} dV_{n+1}
  &= \int_0^{n+1} \iint_{B_u} e^{t(x_1+\dotsb+x_n)} \, dV_n \, e^{tu} \, du \\
  &= \int_0^{n+1} \iint_{B_u} e^{(tu')(x_1/u'+\dotsb+x_n/u')} \, dV_n \, e^{tu} \, du \\
  &= \int_0^{n+1} \iint_A e^{(tu')(x'_1+\dotsb+x'_n)} \, u'^n dV_n \, e^{tu} \, du \\
  &= \int_0^{n+1} \left(\frac{e^{tu'}-1}{tu'}\right)^n u'^n \ e^{tu} \, du \\
  &= \int_0^{n+1} \left(\frac{e^{tu'}-1}{t}\right)^n \ e^{tu} \, du
\end{split}
$$
by induction. To simplify, first substitute $u' = 1 - \frac{u}{n+1}$, so $du' = - \frac{1}{n+1} du$. Then $u = (n+1)(1-u')$. When $u=0$ then $u'=1$, and when $u=n+1$, then $u'=0$. Substituting and reversing the direction of the integral, that last integral is equal to
$$
\begin{split}
  \int_0^1 \left(\frac{e^{tu'}-1}{t}\right)^n  e^{t(n+1)(1-u')} (n+1) du'
  &= \int_0^1 \left(\frac{e^{tu'}-1}{t}\right)^n e^{tn(1-u')} e^{t(1-u')} (n+1) du' \\
  &= \int_0^1 \left(\frac{e^{tu'}-1}{t} e^{t(1-u')}\right)^n e^{t(1-u')} (n+1) du' \\
  &= \int_0^1 \left(\frac{e^t-e^{t(1-u')}}{t}\right)^n e^{t(1-u')} (n+1) du' \\
  &= \int_0^{(e^t-1)/t} v^n (n+1) \, dv,
\end{split}
$$
where $v = \frac{e^t-e^{t(1-u')}}{t}$, $dv = e^{t(1-u')} du'$. And this integral is equal to $\left( \frac{e^t-1}{t} \right)^{n+1}$ as desired.